# z-index not effective even with position set to relative and opacity set to 0.99

Tags: css, html

I have an animated filmstrip containing photo's but am unable to make the filmstrip float on top of the photo's by adjusting the z-index values. I've tried the work around described by Philip Watson who suggests altering the opacity value to alter the stacking context but I'm having trouble implementing it. I've currently got the position set to relative but z-index is still ineffective .
My code can be seen here:

http://pastebin.com/NBdV4wsn

and the filmstrip running here:

http://www.streetpics.co.uk/testingground.html

Thanks for any help with this infuriating problem.

Comment: It is not working because you are using the film strip image as the background image, and as the name goes... you can't make the content go behind the background image. And I would recommend JSFiddle over Pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your z-index is not working because the stacking context is only specific to the children only. No matter how low of a z-index you use for the parent, the children will be in their own stacking context, so they will never go behind the parent.

However, you can always create a psedo-element in the parent container (such that it is in the same stacking context as the images), and overlay it over the images:

```
.film_strip:after {
    background-image: url([filmstrip.gif]);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Because of this, you will no longer need to specify z-index for anything (yay!).

The trick to force the pseudo-element to expand to the full dimension of the parent, when positioned absolutely, is to specify the top, left, bottom and right coordinates as 0.

Here is a proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/pNPm2/

Comment: Thanks Terry for taking the time to provide an excellent answer. It's working perfectly now :)